# Is it possible to build a trilinear map $\tau$ such that

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, multilinear-algebra

$\tau: E^3 \to V$ (where $E,V$ are vector spaces with $char\ne 2$) and such that for all $(x,y,z)\in E^3$, $\tau(x,y,z)=-\tau(y,x,z)$ and $\tau(x,y,z)=\tau(x,z,y)$.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: @ArnaudD. indeed my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\tau(x,y,z) = -\tau(y,x,z) = - \tau(y,z,x) = \tau(z,y,x) 
$$

$$
\tau(x,y,z) = \tau(x,z,y) = - \tau(z,x,y) = -\tau(z,y,x) 
$$

So $\tau\equiv 0$.

Comment: Ok so there is only $\tau \equiv 0$ which can work ? No non-trivial map ?

Comment: Yes, and It holds even if $\tau$ is not trilinear